# Is it possible to apply `first()` and `last()` to separate columns in groupby operation in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'data': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'value': [10, 9, 8, 7]})

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   id  data  value
0   1     1     10
1   1     2      9
2   2     3      8
3   2     4      7

In [5]: df.groupby(['id']).last()
Out[5]: 
    data  value
id             
1      2      9
2      4      7

In [6]: df.groupby(['id']).first()
Out[6]: 
    data  value
id             
1      1     10
2      3      8
```

Is it possible to generate a dataframe from the `groupby` that is made up of `first()` applied to `value` and `last()` applied to `data`? If it makes it easier, you can assume `last()` is applied to everything but `value`, and `first()` is applied only to `value`. I can do it in two separate groupbys, but is it possible in one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a dict of funcs to [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once):

```
In[80]:
df.groupby('id').agg({'data':'last', 'value':['first','last']})
Out[80]: 
   data value     
   last first last
id                
1     2    10    9
2     4     8    7
```

You can pass a list of funcs if you want to call `first` and `last` on the 'value' column. Here `pandas` is able to deduce which method to call by passing just the string name of the funcs

Comment: Thanks! I've never used `agg` before, so this is great :)